# WYSIWYG editor values are not binding with Dropzone form

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, wysiwyg, dropzone.js, summernote

I have an application built in Spring. In JSP I have integrated Dropzone for image uploads.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="services" method="POST" id="service" enctype="multipart/form-data" cssClass="dropzone">

 <form:input path="budget">
 <form:textarea path="informationToBuyer" cssClass="summernote"/>


 <div id="dropzone" class="col-md-8"></div>

<form:form>
```

In above code budget is binding with the spring modelAttribute and informationToBuyer is not binding.

But when I remove the summernote css then it is getting binded.

My JS for Dropzone is as follows.

```
Dropzone.options.service = {
                    // The configuration we've talked about above
                    autoProcessQueue : false,
                    uploadMultiple : true,
                    maxFilesize : 256,
                    parallelUploads : 50,
                    maxFiles : 50,
                    addRemoveLinks : true,
                    clickable : true,
                    previewsContainer : "#dropzone",
                    // The setting up of the dropzone
                    init : function() {

                        var myDropzone = this;

                        // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
                        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]")
                                .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                                    // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                                });

                        // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
                        // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
                        this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
                            // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
                            // Hide the success button or the complete form.
                            myDropzone.processQueue();
                        });

                        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
                            window.location.replace(response.redirect);
                            exit();
                        });
                        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {

                        });

                    }
                };
```

Kindly tell me why WYSIWYG editor is not working with Dropzone form.

Comment: The form is submitting twice, first time the MultipartHttpServletRequest file map is empty and the text area value is there  and second call the text area is empty and the files are present

Comment: I have changed the editor from summer note to an other and now it is working as expected.

Comment: Hi i changed the Summer Note Still its not working